# Node Name in Chef Template?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I've been trying to figure out how to get the node's name (`knife bootstrap -N`) into a template.  I've tried a dozen different ideas and haven't found anything that works yet.  Does anyone know how to access this from a Chef recipe?

Also -- is there a way to list all of the variables available to a Chef recipe?

Answer (score 35):

A cleaner more concise way is shown on the [Attributes](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html#automatic-attributes) wiki page:

```
node.name
```

Comment: This gives the FQDN.  Any way to get the short name?

Comment: I don't know a very chef-ly way to do it, but node.name.split('.')[0] works ok

Comment: You should always use the node[:attribute] syntax when getting chef attributes. The ohai dervied attribute is at node[:hostname]

Comment: @jarrad note that your link is now broken because chef docs have moved. Would you be able to update it to the right one (i think https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html)?

Comment: @Blaskovicz I have updated the answer. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 31):

You can use `Chef::Config[:node_name]` in your recipe. I found this in the chef-client cookbook from Opscode.

Comment: I concur with @anaudmeuret, this solution worked for me in Shef and in a recipe, where the accepted answer did not.

Comment: The original question is how to access node name in a template.  This answer does not work for that.  Actually,  <%= node.name %> is the complete syntax for the .erb file, and is how to access the node name in a template.

Comment: It seems the template syntax and recipe syntax are different.

I've got a template that uses the <%=node.name%> syntax
And just used the above Chef::Config[:node_name] syntax in a recipe

Answer (score 5):

To see all node specific attributes type command

```
knife node edit <name> -a
```

First level keys accessible with "node." prefix.

```
{
  "name": "n1",
  ...
  "hostname": "chef-n1",
  "fqdn": "chef-n1.dan.lan",
  "domain": "dan.lan",
  "ipaddress": "192.168.4.4",
  "macaddress": "52:54:00:72:E7:C5",
```